# Ironpython get type of property of dot net class

Tags: types, ironpython

I would like to write the following function which takes a random Dot Net class that is known to have a property called `Amount` and returns some indication of the Dot Net type of that property.  `Amount` will generally be a nullable type, therefore `instance` will end up with `null` (Python `None`) when created.

```python
def learn_type(test_class):

    '''Given Dot Net class test_class, return the type of the nullable Amount property.'''

    instance = test_class()
    answer = type(instance.Amount) # always NoneType

    return answer
```

What is the proper way to get an indication of the type of `instance.Amount`?

In addition to the code above, I've tried introspecting both `test_class.Amount` and `instance.Amount`. I'm able to obtain a `getset_descriptor`, but I can't determine how to extract a type indicator from that object either.

This is for some ETL code, one of the goals of which is to inform the calling program of bad data types encountered in the input. My code would like to know both what was encountered, and what type was expected.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the type information? How do you want to process the info? Are you interested in .NET types or the equivalent primitive python types?

Comment: My goal is twofold -- to perform a sensible type conversion for a reasonable number of common types, and to provide the calling program with information (including type) about the property I was unable to assign to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the normal .NET System.Reflection APIs:

```
instance = test_class()
answer = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Amount").PropertyType
```

The starting point is [System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx); all of the .NET type metadata is available from there.

Comment: Had to do some additional work for NULLABLE types, but this worked pretty smoothly.